# First differences interpretation

Tags: time-series, interpretation

I have a small issue regarding first difference models. Suppose we have

$$ \Delta y_{t} = \beta_{0} + \beta_{1} \Delta \log{y_{t-1}} + \Delta u_{t} $$

The interpretation of the delta would be the same as if I did with:

$$ y_{t} = \beta_{0} + \beta_{1} \log{y_{t-1}} + u_{t} $$

That is correct right?

However if we have:

$$ \Delta y_{t} = \beta_{0} + \beta_{1} \log{p} + u_{t} $$

Then the interpretation would be if p increases by 1%, the increase in $y_{t}$ would be $\beta_{1}$ right?

Thanks in advance for clearing things up!

Comment: In the last sentence of the interpretation, I realized I made a mistake, it should be the increase in growth of $y_{t}$ would be $\beta_{1}$